# when printing key and value it prints they key+value as many times as I have digits in my value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing, format

I am learning programming in python 3 and I am having a issue with formating 2 for statements inside a list.
Here is how I did it :

```
items = {
    "Iphone X": {"price": 1000, "stock":10},
    "Samsung S9": {"price": 800, "stock":10},
    "Huawei P20": {"price": 600, "stock":10},
    "HTC Vive": {"price": 400, "stock":10}
}
    test = ["{} - {}$".format(nume, pret) for nume in items.keys() for pret in items[nume]["price"]]
    print("\n".join(test))
```

I don't know why when I change the type of `items[nume]["price"]` into `str` it prints the key + the value , it prints it as many digits i have in my value.

If I don't change the type of `items[nume]["price]` it tells me `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` .

Comment: What is that `,` doing there?

Comment: @DeepSpace, I thought I need to sperate the 2 for statements.

Comment: What is `items`?  You're looping over the keys, but also expecting it to have a `price` key?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I added them into the code , sorry I thought I already put them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.items()` to access both the keys and values of your dictionary.

```
d = {'hammer':'5', 'scewdriver':'2'}

test = ["{} - {}$".format(k, v) for k,v in d.items()]
print("\n".join(test))
```

Comment: Hey @BernardL, thank you for taking the time to answer my question, but as far as I know if I am doing the dictionary like that I won't be able to add stock as I have in mine right now.

Comment: @SebastianNeamtu select it by key, `["{} - {}$".format(k, v['price']) for k,v in d.items()]`